# Removing labels when using Heatmap package in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm trying to generate a heatmap with a ton of data (1193 rows, 165 columns) and the row and column labels are coming out completely packed together, overlapping, and ugly. Accordingly, I'd like to remove them and not display any column or row labels at all.

I'm trying to use `labRow = NULL`, but am getting an error message that says `unused argument (labRow = NULL)`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or how I can prevent the row and column labels from displaying? Below is my code.

Thanks so much!

```
Heatmap(filename,name="name of chart", col=colorRamp2(c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
c("firebrick4","firebrick3","firebrick1","darkorange1","gold1", "deepskyblue","dodgerblue","dodgerblue4")),
cluster_rows=FALSE,cluster_column=FALSE, labRow = NULL
```

Comment: I think `Heatmap` should be `heatmap` and also there's a bracket missing at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to change it to `labRow = FALSE` and that should fix the problem.

Comment: OK. Can you provide some sample data with your code so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sure - what's the best way to provide it? I'm new to Stackoverflow, but happy to follow directions if you have a link I can use :-)

Comment: For example `mat <- matrix(rnorm(1193*165), nrow = 1193)` gives you a matrix of normally distributed random values. Run the code with this in matrix in place of yours and post the exact code used and the result.

Comment: I used the code `Heatmap(mat,name="filename",col = colorRamp2(c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),c("firebrick4","firebrick3","firebrick1",darkorange1","gold1","deepskyblue","dodgerblue","dodgerblue4")),cluster_rows=FALSE, cluster_columns=FALSE, labRow = NULL)`. The output is `Error in Heatmap(mat, name = "filename", col = colorRamp2(c(2, 3, 4, 5,  : unused argument (labRow = NULL)`

Comment: There are still mistakes in the code and I can't reproduce the error. Also, what other packages are used?

Comment: I figured it out - the code was: row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 10). Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

leave empty your rownames and colnames of the filename object

```
empty.cols = unlist(lapply(colnames(filename),function(x){
                                            a = " "
                                        } 
                            )
                    )
empty.rows = unlist(lapply(row.names(filename),function(x){
                                            a = " "
                                        } 
                           )
                   )
colnames(filename) = empty.cols
row.names(filename) = empty.rows
```

or if you want to preserve filename object names use

```
heatmap(filename,labRow = empty.rows, labCol = empty.cols)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! However, when I try to run 

`heatmap(filename,labRow = empty.rows, labCol = empty.cols)`  

I get an error message that reads  

`Error in Heatmap(filename, labRow = empty.rows, labCol = empty.cols) : unused arguments (labRow = empty.rows, labCol = empty.cols)`

It seems like the labRow and labCol arguments are not being recognized - do you know how to fix?

Thanks so much!

Comment: So... You said heatmap had 1193 rows and 165 columns. please check if the empty.rows object has 1193 empty strings inside and the empty.cols object has 165 empty strings inside

Comment: @DavidNitkin 
if you can transform your filename object into RDS and send me by email I could help you better

Comment: empty.rows has 1193 empty strings and empty.cols has 165 empty strings.

Comment: Is there a way to perhaps change the font size instead of deleting the text entirely?

Comment: yép, to change font size use:   `heatmap(filename, cexRow = 0.2, cexCol = 0.5)`

Comment: It gives me the same error, unfortunately: `Error in Heatmap(filename, cexRow = 0.2, cexCol = 0.5) : unused arguments (cexRow = 0.2, cexCol = 0.5)`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The answer is `row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 10)`

Thanks, all!

Answer (score 0):

Just set "fontsize_row" or "fontsize_col" to a small number (e.g., 0.001).

Answer (score 0):

```
show_annotation_name = FALSE
```

That will do the trick!